# Matlab putting Subtables in for loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, indexing

Specific problem here. I want to fill in missing data in categorical array which I group indexed. I know how to do it for 1 table but I have to do it for over 489 tables. I want to fill in the missing data into all the subtables.

This is what I tried to do:

```
for k=1:489
%// Change data to an ordinal list
B{k} = grp2idx(subTable{k,1}.Var1);
% Fill missing data points by moving median
[G{k},TG{k}] = fillmissing(B{k},"movmedian",3);
end
```

This is what I got:
Unable to perform assignment because brace indexing is not supported for
variables of this type.

I expected to have 489 arrays of filled in data and then put them into the subtables.

Comment: Could this be because you're trying to use brace indexing with a variable that doesn't support it. In MATLAB, brace indexing is used for accessing cell arrays. It seems to me that that B{k}, G{k}, or TG{k} might not be cell arrays.

To resolve the issue I think you can initialize the cell arrays B, G, and TG before the loop.

Comment: Wow thanks for the answer. Didn't know that it would be so easy haha. Solved it